# Changing a DataGrid cellstyle based on the previous row value

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In a DataGrid - Is there a way to set a cell style based on the value of the cell in the previous row?

Answer (score 1):

During binding, you can access the prior value in the collection by accessing the [RelativeSourceMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx). Specifically, `RelativeSource PreviousData`.

> The string token PreviousData; corresponds to a [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) as
>   created with its [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.mode.aspx) property set to [PreviousData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx).

Here's an example I used when creating a comma separated list of items in XAML and ensuring the last value does not contain a trailing comma:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe Print">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Comma" Text="," />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </TextBlock>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Comma" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This looks to be comparing columns within the same row.  I need to compare the same column across different rows.

Comment: This compares the previous value in the collection; not columns. In other words, the previous row. see the links already included in the answer for more details.